# Using regular html_document YAML tags with RNotebook

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

As the title  - I want to be able to use YAML tags like toc: true and toc_float: true for use in an RNotebook file. Currently I have this:

### ```

title: "R Notebook"
output:
    html_notebook:

### toc:true

## Section 1

This is an [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) Notebook. W

## Section 2

`{r}
plot(cars)`

```

Which gives me an error of : Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning for the next token at line 3, column 1found character that cannot start any token at line 3, column 1

The document loads, but without the toc.

Answer (score 0):

try this exemple from the rstudio basic one

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_notebook:
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
  html_document:
    toc: yes
---

# blabla section 1

This is an [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) Notebook. When you execute code within the notebook, the results appear beneath the code. 

Try executing this chunk by clicking the *Run* button within the chunk or by placing your cursor inside it and pressing *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. 

```{r}
plot(cars)
```

# blabla section 2

Add a new chunk by clicking the *Insert Chunk* button on the toolbar or by pressing *Ctrl+Alt+I*.

When you save the notebook, an HTML file containing the code and output will be saved alongside it (click the *Preview* button or press *Ctrl+Shift+K* to preview the HTML file).
````